# PHP/MySQL output into table with bootstrap - columns are messed

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with mysql output into table. Script is working perfectly, I got data what I need but columns in table are messed. It seems like there might be a problem with these multiple echos, but I tried every possible combination what I found/come up with and nothing worked so far.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo"<table class='table table-hover table-striped table-responsive'>";
        echo"<tr class='table_row'>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td>" . $row['4'] . "</td>";
        echo"<td><a href='#'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></button></a></td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        echo"</table>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must try this :

```
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  echo"<table class='table table-hover table-striped table-responsive'>";
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                    echo"<tr class='table_row'>";
                    echo"<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
                    echo"<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
                    echo"<td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>";
                    echo"<td>" . $row['4'] . "</td>";
                    echo"<td><a href='#'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></button></a></td>";
                    echo"</tr>";

                  }
echo"</table>";
}
```

You are repeating the table inside while loop. Hope this help you.